# Makefile: How to correctly include header file and its directory?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
CC=g++
INC_DIR = ../StdCUtil
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -I$(INC_DIR)
DEPS = split.h

all: Lock.o DBC.o Trace.o

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf *o all
```

This makefile and all three source files `Lock.cpp`, `DBC.cpp`, `Trace.cpp` are located in the current directory called `Core`. One of the source file `Trace.cpp` contains a line that includes a header file outside the current directory:

```
//in Trace.cpp
#include "StdCUtil/split.h"
```

The header file `split.h` is located at one level above the current directory and then in the subdirectory called `StdCUtil`. So that's why I added `INC_DIR = ../StdCUtil` in the makefile. The overall directory structure looks like the following:

```
root
  |___Core
  |     |
  |     |____Makefile
  |     |____DBC.cpp
  |     |____Lock.cpp
  |     |____Trace.cpp
  |
  |___StdCUtil
        |___split.h
```

But when I make it, it gives me the error:

```
Trace.cpp:8:28: fatal error: StdCUtil/split.h: No such file or directory
 #include "StdCUtil/split.h"
                            ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'Trace.o' failed
```

Why this doesn't find the header file `split.h` even if I specify the `INC_DIR` in the makefile? How to correct this?

Comment: By convention (and make uses these variables for implicit rules), `CC` is a C compiler, `CXX` is a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

These lines in your makefile,

```
INC_DIR = ../StdCUtil
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -I$(INC_DIR)
DEPS = split.h
```

and this line in your .cpp file,

```
#include "StdCUtil/split.h"
```

are in conflict.

With your makefile in your source directory and with that `-I` option you should be using `#include "split.h"` in your source file, and your dependency should be `../StdCUtil/split.h`.

Another option:

```
INC_DIR = ../StdCUtil
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -I$(INC_DIR)/..  # Ugly!
DEPS = $(INC_DIR)/split.h
```

With this your `#include` directive would remain as `#include "StdCUtil/split.h"`.

Yet another option is to place your makefile in the parent directory:

```
root
  |____Makefile
  |
  |___Core
  |     |____DBC.cpp
  |     |____Lock.cpp
  |     |____Trace.cpp
  |
  |___StdCUtil
        |___split.h
```

With this layout it is common to put the object files (and possibly the executable) in a subdirectory that is parallel to your `Core` and `StdCUtil` directories. `Object`, for example. With this, your makefile becomes:

```
INC_DIR = StdCUtil
SRC_DIR = Core
OBJ_DIR = Object
CFLAGS  = -c -Wall -I.
SRCS = $(SRC_DIR)/Lock.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/DBC.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/Trace.cpp
OBJS = $(OBJ_DIR)/Lock.o $(OBJ_DIR)/DBC.o $(OBJ_DIR)/Trace.o
# Note: The above will soon get unwieldy.
# The wildcard and patsubt commands will come to your rescue.

DEPS = $(INC_DIR)/split.h
# Note: The above will soon get unwieldy.
# You will soon want to use an automatic dependency generator.


all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/Trace.o: $(DEPS)
```

Comment: Thanks David. The second approach you marked as "ugly" actually works! I also tried the first approach in which I just use `#include "split.h"` in `Trace.cpp` but I still get the same error. Don't know why the first approach doesn't work. I haven't had time to try the third way yet. Will report back after I try it.

Comment: It turns out that both the first and third option work. I found out that I need to change the dependency variable to be `DEPS = $(INC_DIR)/StdCUtil/split.h` and this way I don't need to modify the source code include and it remains as `#include "StdCUtil/split.h"`. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Does the "." immediately after "-I" refer to the current directory?  The syntax seems somehow awkward, like I'd expect a space or an "=" between them.  Is that just me?

Comment: @AlexJohnson -- That's exactly what it means. The gcc documentation says that the `-I` option is specified as `-Idir`, where `dir` is the name of the directory to be added to the include path. `-I=dir` would add the directory `=dir` to the include path. (But `-I dir` with a space between the `-I` and the path to the directory does seem to work.)

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor is looking for `StdCUtil/split.h` in

- `./` (i.e. `/root/Core/`, [the directory that contains the #include statement](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)). So `./` + `StdCUtil/split.h` = `./StdCUtil/split.h` and the file is missing

and in

- `$INC_DIR` (i.e. `../StdCUtil/` = `/root/Core/../StdCUtil/` = `/root/StdCUtil/`). So `../StdCUtil/` + `StdCUtil/split.h` = `../StdCUtil/StdCUtil/split.h` and the file is missing

You can fix the error changing the `$INC_DIR` variable (best solution):

```
$INC_DIR = ../
```

or the include directive:

```
#include "split.h"
```

but in this way you lost the "path syntax" that makes it very clear what namespace or module the header file belongs to.

Reference:

- [C++ #include semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179213/c-include-semantics)

EDIT/UPDATE

It should also be

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -c -Wall -I$(INC_DIR)

...

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Comment: Thanks manilo. Actually I tried using `INC_DIR = ../` but it gives me the same error information. I also feel strange on this error.

Comment: You are right, we must change also CC with CXX=g++ and CFLAGS=... with CXXFLAGS=...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question about make, it is a question about the semantic of the `#include` directive.

The problem is, that there is no file at the path "../StdCUtil/StdCUtil/split.h". This is the path that results when the compiler combines the include path "../StdCUtil" with the relative path from the `#include` directive "StdCUtil/split.h".

To fix this, just use `-I..` instead of `-I../StdCUtil`.

Comment: Thanks cmaster. Actually I tried using `INC_DIR = ../` or `INC_DIR = ..` but they give me the same error. I also feel very strange on this.

Comment: From which directory do you execute `make`?

Comment: I run make from Core directory which is the directory where the Makefile is located.

Comment: Would you mind posting the actual compiler call that is generated by `make`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `INC_DIR=../ ../StdCUtil`.

Then, set `CCFLAGS=-c -Wall $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIR))`

EDIT: Also, modify your `#include` to be `#include <StdCUtil/split.h>` so that the compiler knows to use -I rather than local path of the .cpp using the `#include`.

Comment: I feel silly too. Just realized that you are using reserved words in make - namely `CC` and `CFLAGS`. `CC` should be `CXX` and `CFLAGS` should be `CXXFLAGS`. Then, your command for your %.o target is `$(CXX) -o $@ $<`

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to switch from `#include "foo/bar.h"` to `#include <foo/bar.h>`. The standard is not at all clear on the difference between the two; it's implementation-defined. In practice, unless you use some rather advanced flags, the difference between the two forms on most compilers oftentimes is amazingly small. `#include "foo/bar.h"` first searches in the directory that contains the file being compiled and then reverts to `#include <foo/bar.h>`. Amongst programmers, `#include <foo/bar.h>` typically means "`foo/bar.h` is something my team didn't write".

Comment: @DavidHammen: Agreed on this.