# Why can I not include this file correctly using a makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

My directory structure looks like this:

```
root
  |____SG
  |     |
  |     |____Makefile
  |     |____simple_client_main.cpp
  |
  |___EEE
        |___my_utils.h
```

SG is essentially my base of operations for building "simple_client", and I'm running make from here. In `simple_client_main.cpp` I have the following #includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "my_utils.h"
```

So I need my makefile to know where `my_utils.h` is. With this in mind, I want to add the root/EEE directory as an include directory. (From where I am, that would be ../EEE.)

Following the advice suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545029/makefile-how-to-correctly-include-header-file-and-its-directory), my makefile looks like this:

```
DIR1 = ../EEE

CXXFLAGS = $(FLAG)

OBJS = simple_client_main.o
SRCS = simple_client_main.cpp

all: simple_client

simple_client: $(OBJS)
        g++ -o simple_client -I$(DIR1) $(OBJS) -lz

# [...]

depend:
        makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) -- $(SRCS)
```

But it doesn't work:

```
simple_client_main.cpp:6:25: fatal error: my_utils.h: No such file or directory 
compilation terminated.
```

Note that if I manually set the #include directive in the cpp as follows:

```
#include "../EEE/my_utils.h"
```

...everything works as expected.

What am I likely to be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-I$(DIR1)` to either `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS` (or perhaps both), so that when the object file is compiled, the option is present in the compiler command line.

You want `make` to execute something similar to:

```
g++ -c -I../EEE simple_client_main.cpp
```

It should do that if you add `-I../EEE` to `$(CXXFLAGS)` or `$(CFLAGS)`.  You need to know the rules used by the `make` program you're using — they can vary.

When linking object files, it is too late for the `-I` option to be of relevance (but you should still include `$(CFLAGS)` or `$(CXXFLAGS)` in the linker command line as other options, notably `-g`, are of relevance when linking as well as when compiling to object code).

Here is some simple modifications to the outline `makefile` shown in the question.

```
DIR1     = ../EEE
IFLAGS   = -I$(DIR1)
CXXFLAGS = $(FLAG) $(IFLAGS)
CFLAGS   = $(IFLAGS)
LDFLAGS  =
LDLIBS   = -lz
CXX      = g++

OBJS = simple_client_main.o
SRCS = simple_client_main.cpp

all: simple_client

simple_client: $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

A makefile like this stands a modest chance of working correctly.  It is not clear what you might put in the `FLAG` macro, so I've left it.  (I use `UFLAGS` and `UXXFLAGS` for 'user-defined C (or C++) flags'; they can be set on the command line and are never set by the `makefile` and are included in the `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS` — you may be after something similar.)

Note how the linking line is almost all macros.  This is normal and desirable; macros can be changed when running `make` without editing the `makefile`, but constant text cannot be changed without editing the `makefile`.  The `-c` and `-o` options to the C and C++ compilers are about all that should ever appear as plain text.

If there are still problems, look at the built-in rule for compiling C++ source code to an object file, and tweak definitions accordingly. (You can use `make -p` to print the rules — you may need that to find out what is going on, but I hope not for your sake because they tend to be complex.  Using `make -f /dev/null -p` shows the built-in rules only; that can be useful, too.)

Note that the `make depend` rule may need some surgery.  It uses `$(CFLAGS)`.  If `$(CXXFLAGS)` contains extra options that are needed by the `makedepend` command, then you may need that instead, or even as well.  If you have only C++ source, you probably only need the `$(CXXFLAGS)` macro in the command line.

Answer (score -1):

Is the error coming from the compile stage, or the makedepend stage?

Because what I see above is that makedepend uses `$(CFLAGS)`, and you haven't put `-I$(DIR1)` into `CFLAGS`.

Comment: This could be a comment, but I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: you are probably right. But I can't put a paragraph break in a comment

Comment: How would one go about putting -I$(DIR1) into CFLAGS? What is the syntax?

Comment: How to put it in CFLAGS depends somewhat on the dialect of Make, and whether there's a CFLAGS already specified. Probably something like CFLAGS += -I${DIR1}

Comment: or just put the -I$(DIR1) in the makedepend command line as well as in the g++ command line

Comment: Like this? `makedepend -I$(DIR1) -- $(CFLAGS) -- $(SRCS)` ? Appears not to work.