# How to write a Makefile for structured file system

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to learn how to write makefiles for my projects. Given that I'm using a text editor like sublime-text and the terminal.

I know how to write a makefile to compile a single file and it's relevant header files IF all files are in the same directory.

Imagine that we have a directory and some sub-directories which are structured like this:

the `Headers` contains all the `.h` files `Objects` is a directory to hold the `.o` files and `Sources` is a directory that has the source codes `.cpp` The `Makefile` is in the top level directory.

```
.
├── Headers
│   └── function.h
├── Makefile
├── Objects
│   └── main.o
└── Sources
    ├── function.cpp
    └── main.cpp
```

I have tried to put together a `Makefile` by following the [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading) and the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545029/makefile-how-to-correctly-include-header-file-and-its-directory).

At the moment my Makefile looks like this:

```
INC_DIR = Headers
SRC_DIR = Sources
OBJ_DIR = Objects
CXXFLAGS = -c -Wall -I.
CC = g++

SRCS = $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp 
OBJS = $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o

DEPS = $(INC_DIR)/*.h

output: $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(OBJ_DIR)/function.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS)  $< -o $@

clean: 
    rm $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o output
```

Which will generate the following error when `make` is executed

```
g++ -c -Wall -I.  Sources/function.cpp -o Objects/function.o
Sources/function.cpp:2:22: fatal error: function.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'Objects/function.o' failed
make: *** [Objects/function.o] Error 1
```

I know that I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what and how to fix it.

I'd appreciate any help and guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Headers` to your `CXXFLAGS`:

```
 CXXFLAGS = -c -Wall -I. -IHeaders
                       # ^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Also you rather might want to generate header dependencies using GCC's `-M<x>` option family and include these into your Makefile.

Here's a pretty good explanation for the technique from GNU make's documentation:

[**4.14 Generating Prerequisites Automatically**](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html)

more info can be also found here:

[**Makefile (Auto-Dependency Generation)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025766/makefile-auto-dependency-generation)

Comment: what is the `-M<x>` option and how do i use it?

Comment: I'm trying to learn the -M (Auto prerequisites).
So what does `-IHeaders` do exactly in the  `CXXFLAGS`?

Comment: @Amir It adds the directory path for searching header files to GCC's build options. So you can write `#include "function.h"` in your source code and GCC will automatically lookup any directory passed with the `-I` option.

Comment: So if the `Headers` file name changes the `-IHeaders` will change respectively?

Comment: @Amir If you mean the directory name changes from e.g. `Headers` to `Includes`, then yes you have to change that accordingly.