# Make file for including files from parent folder

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am working on a project with the following dir structure.

```
prog/
    Makefile
    src/
        module1/
        module2/
        common/
            util.c
            util.h           # include "common/info.h"
            info.c
            info.h
    test/
        perf/
            Makefile
            src/
                test.c
```

I needed a use functions of `prog/src/common/util.c` in `prog/test/src/test.c` 
I copied all files from `prog/src/common/*` in new folder `prog/test/src/common/` 
Then I added the `INC_DIR` in `CFLAGS` of `Makefile`

`prog/test/perf/Makefile`:

```
INC_DIR = src/common
DFLAGS  = -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(O)/$*.d
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Werror $(OPT) $(STD) -I$(INC_DIR)../
```

but i am still getting error when i `make`

`src/common/util.h:4:24 fatal error common/info.h: No such file or directory`

I checked that `prog/test/src/common/info.h` does exist.
I am not so good at Makefile syntax. What am i doing wrong.

Comment: It's not the Makefile syntax, it's the paths you provide. You tell the compiler to search "src/common" and give it a file "common/info.h". Do you see the error? It looks for "src/common/common/info.h"

Comment: `-I` flag is `src/common/../`  I referred this ans : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22545645

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that you changed the path in the option, sorry. However, actually it's "src/common../" (no slash before the dots).