# How can I add a path to a Makefile?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

In C++, I have a library path I know how include when building with a CMakeLists.txt file but I don't know how to include it when building with a Makefile.

I tried applying the solution [asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545029/makefile-how-to-correctly-include-header-file-and-its-directory) but it didn't work. The contents of the Makefile is below. The library's name is "NumCpp". The full path to this library on my computer is `C:\Users\ooo\tor\Robot\rainbow\NumCpp\include\`.
In the .cc file I am including the library as `#include "NumCpp.hpp"`

This is the CMakeLists.txt file. This would include and compile the NumCpp library if you ran this in the directory containing NumCpp. I don't know if it is helpful to show this, but I know I can include the library this way.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project("HelloWorld" CXX)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

find_package(NumCpp 2.6.2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    NumCpp::NumCpp
)
```

The Makefile. I tried using `INC_DIR`, `CFLAGS`, and `DEPS` to link the path to the library but I'm getting an error.

```
COMMON=/O2 /MT /EHsc /arch:AVX /I../include /Fe../bin/
cl_vars = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe'
cl_var = 'cl'

INC_DIR = C:/Users/ooo/tor/Robot/rainbow/NumCpp/include/
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -I$(INC_DIR)
DEPS = NumCpp.hpp

all:
    $(cl_var) $(COMMON) testxml.cc                 ../bin/mujoco210nogl.lib
    $(cl_var) $(COMMON) testspeed.cc               ../bin/mujoco210nogl.lib
    $(cl_var) $(COMMON) compile.cc                 ../bin/mujoco210nogl.lib
    $(cl_var) $(COMMON) derivative.cc /openmp      ../bin/mujoco210nogl.lib
    $(cl_var) $(COMMON) basic.cc ../bin/glfw3.lib  ../bin/mujoco210.lib
    $(cl_var) $(COMMON) record.cc ../bin/glfw3.lib ../bin/mujoco210.lib
    $(cl_var) $(COMMON) simulate.cc ../include/uitools.c ../bin/glfw3.lib ../bin/mujoco210.lib
    del *.obj
```

The error...

```
simulate.cc(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'NumCpp.hpp': No such file or directory
Generating Code...
Compiling...
uitools.c
Generating Code...
make: *** [Makefile:16: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Always use forward-slashes as directory separators in makefiles, not backslashes.  Also, this makefile is pretty useless.  You might as well just write a `.bat` batch file and put the compile lines in it, then you wouldn't need to worry about backslashes.  You're just using the makefile as a glorified batch file and not taking advantage of any of the things that make makefiles useful, such as avoiding unnecessary recompilation etc.

Comment: Hm.  Looking closer it doesn't seem like you're using the `CFLAGS`, `INC_DIR`, or `DEPS` variables at all anywhere in your makefile anyway.  Just assigning those variables doesn't actually do anything, unless you reference them somewhere.  I suppose you want to use the `COMMON` variable, to add include paths.

Comment: "use the COMMON variable" I tried forward slashes and that didn't do the trick. Do I just write `COMMON` and then the path? There already is a line using `COMMON`. When I added my path to it I got... `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\ooo\tor\Robot\rainbow\NumCpp\include\.obj'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line assigns a value to a makefile variable named `COMMON`:

```
COMMON=/O2 /MT /EHsc /arch:AVX /I../include /Fe../bin/
```

this line assigns a value to a makefile variable name `cl_var`:

```
cl_var = 'cl'
```

These lines in the recipe *use* (or "expand") the variables `cl_var` and `COMMON`:

```
$(cl_var) $(COMMON) testxml.cc ../bin/mujoco210nogl.lib
```

(etc.)

Note that nowhere in your makefile do you ever *use* the variables `cl_vars`, `CFLAGS`, `INC_DIR`, or `DEPS`, so those variable assignments are basically no-ops: useless.  They might as well not be there at all, they have no effect on your makefile.

If you want to add a new directory to the include path, then you have to add it to the `COMMON` variable, because that's the variable that will be used.  Since you're using Visual C++, not a POSIX compiler like GCC or Clang, the syntax is `/I<path>`, not `-I<path>`.

So, you should try something like this:

```
INC_DIR = C:/Users/ooo/tor/Robot/rainbow/NumCpp/include/

COMMON = /O2 /MT /EHsc /arch:AVX /I../include /I$(INC_DIR) /Fe../bin/
```

If you need more orientation, you probably need to read at least the introduction to something like the [GNU make user's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html) to get yourself a basic understanding of what a makefile is and how it works.  SO is not equipped to provide full-fledged tutorials.